# Running command "sudo lshw -C network" and no results

Tags: wireless, asus

I am running ubuntu 17.04 on asus netbook x205ta and when I run the command `sudo lshw -C network` I am getting nothing. It looks like the command runs and then it just does nothing. I am trying to get the wifi working, but cannot. I have been at this for 8.3 hours now =/

Comment: How about: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

Comment: @chili555 Still shows nothing , just goes to the next line , same as before

Comment: @chili555 I have done a lot of research and cannot figure out this. Everything everyone says to do does not work at all for mine.

Comment: Does `sudo lshw` or `lspci` or `lsusb` report anything at all? If not, I think you have a very serious problem and I'd consider a careful backup and reinstall.

Comment: I ended up getting it to work :) With some help , I made another post about it.

Answer (score 0):

I have Xubuntu on my Asus X205TA (I used to use Debian then Lubuntu but they had a few oddities on the X205TA so I made the switch), here is what I did to get mine working with Xubuntu:

The prep work needed:

- Have 2 USB drives (We will call them B1 and B2), an Ubuntu 14.04 64bit ISO, and a Xubuntu 64bit ISO and another computer (not the X205TA)
- Use Rufus on the computer to make a Ubuntu 14.04 Live USB on the first USB drive (B1)
- Boot up the computer with the 14.04 Live USB (B1)
- Use the "startup disk creator" to make a Xubuntu Live USB with persistence on the second USB drive (B2)
- [Add this file](https://github.com/jfwells/linux-asus-t100ta/blob/master/boot/bootia32.efi) to /EFI/BOOT directory of the Xubuntu flash drive (B2)
- Shut down the computer
- Ensure that the laptop is plugged in and charging
- Plug the Xubuntu Live USB drive (B2) into the laptop
- Plug in your internet access device
- Boot the laptop & press ESC as it is booting (this will give you the boot order screen)
- Select "enter setup"
- Disable Secure Boot
- Save and exit the BIOS
- Press ESC as it is booting (this will give you the boot order screen)
- Select your Xubuntu Live USB drive (B2) drive from the list
- Select "Try Xubuntu" when prompted
- Open the "Terminal Emulator" program

Type in the following commands (or you could copy and paste them)

- sudo apt update
- sudo apt install gnome-disk-utility

Then do the following:

- Open the "Disks" program
- Find the laptops inbuilt storage and format it with a MBR/DOS partition system (top right, the gear)
- Once it is done use the "Install Xubuntu" program on the desktop to install it onto the laptops internal storage, make sure you have internet access on the laptop (USB cell phone tethering works well) and to select the option to install third party software.
- When the installation is complete you can shut-down the laptop & remove the USB Drive (but not your internet access device).
- Boot into your new install and log in

You now should have a semi working laptop, but as Billy Mays often said, "But wait there's more".

Open up the terminal and type in the following commands (or you could copy and paste them)

- sudo apt update
- sudo apt dist-upgrade
- Install any updates shown
- sudo reboot

If you are installing 18.04 then your Wifi and MicroSD card reader should be working fine but if you are experiencing system frezes then use the fix in postscript 1, or Wifi stability issues then use the fix in postscript 4. If you are installing version **17.10 or earlier.** then follow postscripts 1, 2, 3, & 4 below.

---

^1 System freezes.

Open up the terminal and type in the following command

- sudo thunar
- Navigate to "/etc/default/"
- Open the "grub" file
- On the line "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT" needs to be edited to read

  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
- Save and close the file
- Close the file manager window

Type into the terminal

- sudo update-grub
- Let it run it's course
- sudo reboot
- All going well you should not experience any random system freezes

---

^2 Wifi driver install for **version 17.10 or earlier.**

Open up the terminal and type in the following commands (or you could copy and paste them)

- cd /tmp
- wget https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/broadcom/wlan/+archive/master/bcmdhd/firmware/bcm43341.tar.gz
- tar xf bcm43341.tar.gz
- sudo mkdir -p /lib/firmware/brcm/
- sudo cp fw_bcm43341.bin /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43340-sdio.bin
- sudo mount -t efivarfs efivarfs /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
- sudo cp /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/nvram-74b00bd9-805a-4d61-b51f-43268123d113 /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43340-sdio.txt
- reboot

---

^3 Micro SD Card Reader fix for **version 17.10 or earlier.**

- Open the text editor and type the following text (as shown) into it

  # Adjustment to make micro SD card reader work
    options sdhci debug_quirks=0x8000
- Save the file as "sdhci.conf" on the desktop

Open up the terminal and type in the following command

- sudo thunar
- Move the "sdhci.conf" file from the desktop to the directory "/etc/modprobe.d"
- Close the file manager window

Type into the terminal

- sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
- Let it run it's course
- sudo reboot

---

^4 Wifi stability fix for **version 17.10 or earlier.**

- Open the text editor and type the following text into it

  blacklist btsdio
- Save the file as "fix-wifi.conf" on the desktop

Open up the terminal and type in the following command

- sudo thunar
- Move the "fix-wifi.conf" file from the desktop to the directory "/etc/modprobe.d"
- Close the file manager window

Type into the terminal

- sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
- Let it run it's course
- sudo reboot
- All going well your Micro SD card reader should now be working and the Wifi should not be working erratically

---

**Note: As of the posting of this "how to" the laptops Bluetooth and sound are not supported and will not work, if you need either of them you will need a USB dongle.**